# Commutation of definitive integral derivatives

Tags: derivatives, definite-integrals

I have a statement:

$$\int_{1}^{x}\frac {d }{d x}\sinh(x)\ \mathrm{d}y$$
which is obviously trivial:
$$\int_{1}^{x}\frac {d }{d x}\sinh(x)\ \mathrm{d}y = \cosh(x)(x-1)$$

But my question is: Do derivation and integration operations have commutative property?

In other words, is it eligible to change the order? Can I write it this way:

$$\frac {d }{d x}\int_{1}^{x}\sinh(x)\ \mathrm{d}y $$

I assume this is wrong, because
$$\frac {d }{d x}\int_{1}^{x}\sinh(x)\ \mathrm{d}y = \frac {d }{d x}(\sinh(x) (x-1)) $$
and now we have to take the derivative which yields:
$$ \frac {d }{d x}(\sinh(x) (x-1)) = \cosh(x)(x-1)+\sinh(x)$$

Since the results are not consistent, am I right to say definitive integration and derivation do not have commutative property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, differentiation and integration are not *strictly* commutative, in this case the commutation fails because your variable of differentiation appears in the bounds for the integral.

The proper statement for changing the order between differentiation and integration can be found in the Leibniz rule for differentiating under the integral sign, which can be applied here as such:

$$\frac{d}{dx} \int^x_1 \sinh(x) dy = \left[\sinh(x) \frac{dy}{dx}\right] ^{y=x}_{y=1} + \int_1^x \frac{d}{d x} \sinh(x) dy = \sinh(x)+ \int_1^x \frac{d}{dx} \sinh(x) dy$$

$$= \sinh(x) + \cosh(x)\big(x-1\big)$$

which matches your result.

Comment: Thank you! Does it have to be $$sinh(x) \frac {d}{dx}y \Bigg|^{y=x}_{y=1} $$ right after the equal sign? And I am sorry I do not fully understand, this result does not match the initial statement  $$\int_{1}^{x}\frac {d }{d x}\sinh(x)\ \mathrm{d}y$$

Comment: You're right, I confused myself a little there. That is meant to be a $\sinh(x),$ I'll fix that right away. As for the second part I meant that the result we obtain here is the same as the result you got when you computed $\frac{d}{dx} \int^x_1 \sinh(x) dy$ yourself, this will not be the same as $\int_1^x \frac{d}{dx} \sinh(x) dy.$ My goal in doing this was to show that expanding using the full form of the Leibniz goal would give the correct answer, which agrees with your working out.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know, is there a way to rewrite the initial statement $$\int_{1}^{x}\frac {d }{d x}\sinh(x)\ \mathrm{d}y$$ using variable upper limit in order to get the consistent result? Or there is just not feasible to rewrite it in the right way?

Comment: Essentially you would just have to add the $f(x,b(x)) b'(x)$ term from the Leibniz rule, so just add the $\sinh(x)$ to the front. If you'd like you can think of this as a contribution from the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: Thank you very much!